# Prove that if certain conditions are met, $p$ does not appear in prime power decomp. of $2n$ choose $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working out of Dudley and am having troubles with the following problem: Prove that if $p$ is odd and $2n/3 < p \le n$, then $p$ does not appear in the prime-power decomposition of $\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}$.

This is equivalent to the statement that $p \nmid \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$. I know that $p < 2n$, since $p$ is odd and in general $p \le 2n$. I'm just a bit lost after this, and don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Try modyfying the legendre formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdots(n+1)}{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots1}$$
and consider the multiples of $p$ dividing numerator and denominator.  We have
$$\tfrac23n<p\le n\ ,\quad \tfrac43n<2p\le2n\ ,\quad 2n<3p\le3n$$
so $p$ is a factor of the denominator, $2p$ is a factor of the numerator, and subsequent multiples of $p$ are factors of neither numerator nor denominator.  Therefore the numerator has a factor of $p$ once, so does the denominator, these cancel and the quotient has no factor of $p$ at all.